# Rails model relationship :through and :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have the following model (only included major details) where there are `Courts` and their time are split into `CourtTimeSlots` which may be `reserved` by any `Users` - more or less described below.
How do I set up such a relationship? Should `User` have many `CourtTimeSlots` :through `Reservation`?

The aim is to be able to get all reservations and from there display the `User` and `Court` information.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    ???
end

class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :court_number
    has_many :court_sessions
end

class CourtTimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :start_time, :end_time, :status
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see. In that case, the following may achieve your goal, demonstrating how to access the data you are looking for through the reservation.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :time_slot
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end

class CourtTimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reservation
  belongs_to :court
end

class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :court_time_slots
end

Reservations.all.each do |r|
  r.user
  r.time_slot.court.court_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking in this direction, but though that the tight connection between User/CourtTimeSlot sounds wrong. The CourtTimeSlot is something that strictly belongs to the Court. The reservation is meant a loose connection/ownership between the User and the CourtTimeSlot.